# Managing several different screen sizes

Tags: jquery, css

I am working a project for mobile IOS,

It came to me that I should start worrying about different screen sizes, the default size for all my `CSS` objects are for the iphone 6 resolution, default `320px x 536px`.

I started adding in Iphone 6 compalitbility using JS to detect the screen size, it does not look good when I resize stuff using the jQuery object `.css(..)`

Someone refrenced me to using the following.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
#obj1 {
      blabla: blabla
  }
}
```

The only issue with this is I have to wrap the `@media screen and...` around every single css object I have?? Or can I just wrap it around all my divs in`CSS`, I have like 300 `CSS` Objects right now and It would be sooo annoying to wrap the `@media...` on every single one.

Comment: use **[bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**, then you can handle all phone screen sizes

Comment: I think you're confusing a couple of very different concepts here. The first is retina screens (double and triple density screens). You can handle that a number of ways, but typically you make the larger images and then size them in CSS. The other issue is responsive layouts where you re-configure your layout via CSS using the @media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set to all your divs one class, in order to avoid going one by one by id.

```
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
<div class="myclass"></div>
@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
.myclass {
      blabla: blabla
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have like 300 divs, it is a little late for me to that :=(

Comment: No. In your IDE or Text editor just find "<div" then replace it with "<div class='myclass' " - if you have Notepad++ you can select the area you want to replace.

Comment: That's merely one way to handle it. To give a specific answer we need to see the specific HTML. Also, if you want this apply to *all* divs, there's no need to give it a class at all.

Comment: But each one of my divs are for a object in my game they all have different  `CSS` properties wouldn't making it all one class make them all the same??

Comment: @Nick you can have multiple classes in one element. `<div class="myclass myOtherclass">`

Answer (score 0):

You should build a responsize design.  Bootstrap has a really awesome solution for building a responsive design based on a 12 column layout. You can apply classes to the layout to decide what shows up based on how much space is available. Read more about it here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

W3Schools has an explanation about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp